# Link with ms-windows-store: navigates to music player instead Windows Store

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store, winrt-async

I am developing Universal App. One of my buttons should navigate user to store page for reviewing the app. I have following code:

```
void BtnRate_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp"));
    }
```

According to [Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn770213(v=vs.105).aspx) this link navigates to review page of current app. For me, any link starting with ms-windows-store opens in music player in Windows Phone and leads to error page in Windows. Why is that? Does anyone hint how to fix that? Thanks in regards for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to works, you have to :

- Associate the app with the Store,
- Have at least a version of the app published/available through the store.

I highly recommend you to use the version providing the appid :

```
ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=[app ID]
```

Regards